# Questions regarding Homogeneous Differential Equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have problem with two differential Equation solutions done in my text book.

I am begginer in this field. I know only Uniqueness Existence Theorem and few methods.

$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{y^2- x^2}{2xy}$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$ and $y(1)=1$

For the first one , they put $y = vx$ and got the solution $y^2+x^2= 2x$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$.

But my doubt is following.

It is clear from the question that the ***differential equation is defined on the set $\mathbb R - A$ where $A = \{ (x,y) : xy = 0\}$. so clearly solution of this differential equation should have been defined on that set only.  I can not understand how they are getting solution for the whole $\mathbb R^2$.***

For the second one , they  have done in the following way.

$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$ implies  $\frac{dx}{dy}= \frac{x^2-y^2}{2xy}$

After that they have put $x$ in the place of y and vice-versa in the previous solution to get the solution of this differential equation.

I can not understand ***how $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$ implies  $\frac{dx}{dy}= \frac{x^2-y^2}{2xy}$. Why are they not caring about what will happen when $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}=0$ ?***

Can anyone please help me ? I got stuck on this and I can not go ahead without understanding this. PLease help me.

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely correct, the points where the denominator is zero usually give a vertical tangent in the solution, that is, a point on the solution curve where it is not differentiable. These points do not belong to the solution function in that it is a differentiable function.

In the first case, you have $y=\sqrt{x(2-x)}$ as the solution branch with the initial point, this is only a differentiable function on $(0,2)$. In the second case, $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ solves to $y=1\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$, $x\in(-1,1)$. The solution is not unique as the initial point is not in the domain of the ODE, that is, where the right side is a smooth function. The initial condition is only reachable as limit of the ODE solutions.

Comment: Can I write $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$ implies $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{2yx}$  ?@Lutz Lehmann

Comment: I can not understand your answer properly. Can you please elaborate it ?@Lutz Lehman

Comment: what is the meaning of solution branch ? Is it the whole solution ?@Lutz Lehman

Comment: How can you get that solution branch ?@Lutz Lehman

Comment: Yes, if both expressions are non-singular. You get branches when solving algebraic equations, or other equations that do not have a unique solution. The correct branch gets selected by additional properties like a point that it has to contain. Are the other questions about the solution of the quadratic equations or a previous stage?

Comment: i can not understand your arguement. Can you please elaborate little more ?@Lutz Lehmann

Comment: $(1,1)$ is not belonging to the domain of $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$ . Can we say the solution of this differential equation will contain $(1,1)$ ?@lut Lehmann

Comment: You can search for solutions that contain this point as a limit. As you have an algebraic curve as implicit form of the solution, this is especially simple here.